# Motors' current exceeds adapter limitation

Tags: power-supply, motor

I've been playing with a motorized [IKEA Bekant](https://www.ikea.com/gb/en/p/bekant-corner-desk-right-sit-stand-linoleum-blue-white-s39282353) table and made an Arduino-based circuit to control its brushed DC motors via [Pololu DRV8874](https://thepihut.com/products/pololu-drv8874-single-brushed-dc-motor-driver-carrier). To my surprise, the [regulated power supply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regulated_power_supply) reports ~3.5 A when the table goes up, which exceeds the current limit printed on the original power supply (2 A, 29 V). If I regulate the current by PWM such that it does not go above 2 A, the table moves unusually slowly (and makes a high-pitched sound I don't recognize ). Unfortunately I don't have the original iDrive boards to check how much it was drawing in the beginning, but I see three options:

- The label on the power adapter does not mean what I think it means.
- The original iDrive board was magical and could make 3.5 A out of 2 A.
- The discrepancy does in fact exist in the design.

It's likely my understanding is lacking, what am I missing?

[image: Power adapter]
[image: iDrive board]

Comment: (1) My first suggesting is to get a 5A max power adapter. (2) Motor starting current can be a couple of times of operating current.

Comment: it could very well be that the original driver of the motor was a buck converter steppping down the 29V to maybe like 24V or even lower whilst increasing the current.

Comment: It's even worse: 2A only at a duty cycle of 10%! Thermal overload expected after 60 s

Comment: @tlfong01 (1) definitely sounds reasonable, (2) is taken care of (sort of) by PMW.

Comment: @Password Oh, you may be right! I didn't know about buck converters, but the motors themselves are 24V.

Comment: @Jens Well, to be fair, it's unlikely the motors would work a minute or more though.

Comment: @Paul Yes, absolutely, until there are little children in the house, who have fun with it :)

Comment: @Jens Haha! I wonder if the adapter has any protective mechanisms at all, a bit hard to say from the label.

Comment: I bet the squealing noise is the frequency that your power supply chops the current in constant current mode.

Comment: @Bryan Hm, it sounds like it's coming from the motors themselves.

Comment: @Paul yep, the supply would create a current ripple and the motors would convert that ripple into sound like a speaker. That’s my guess anyways.

Comment: @Password Based on a quick research on buck converters it appears that ultimately P_in = P_out, which means we are pretty much limited to I_out = (V_in * I_in) / V_out ≈ 2.4 -- below our target. Is that right?

Comment: @Bryan Ah, got it.

Comment: @Paul , Yes thats right , the power output will always be a bit less than input depending on efficiency. If its 24V motors then something is definitely amiss with the adapter specs. As you rightly calculated 24V it would be atmost 2.4A. It could very well be that the adapter is really specced for 2A but because its pulling full power for a short while it could manage 3A. This is something a manufacturer will sometimes do but it required them to work with the supplier.

Comment: https://www.btod.com/blog/problems-ikea-bekant-desk/

Comment: @Password Fantastic, thanks for the explanation. It'd be interesting to see what they came up with the supplier in the end in terms of safety guarantees. Anyway, I'm going to get a 24V, ≥ 5 A adapter replacement to sleep better.